# Detect OS and Assign Stylesheet page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to detect Window operation system and assign a stylesheet page for Window only.  Below is the code:

```
$(function() {
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1)
            {
                $(document.body).append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/scss/ts-v2-window-style.css'>");
            }
        });
```

It works: Mac avoids this code and Window runs inside this, but a problem is It doesn't understand `$`.  What is wrong in this code and how to get it work?

Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How are you loading jquery? Attach the code in your question

Comment: Don't detect the OS directly.  Detect features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load jquery before your script to get $. $ is from jquery library and its not yet loaded when your script runs. Write following in your html code

```
<script src="path_to_jquery_lib"></script>
<script>
//your script as in question
</script>
```

order is important. Also $(function(){}) is a jquery consrtuct to check dom loaded event

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!  As you mentioned, I just updated my question.  This time, it doesn't understand `$` (function() {

Comment: @abcidd you are not including jquery properly, post the code you used to include jquery